# How to change the text of a TextView within an interface

Tags: android, interface

everybody.
Actually I'm doing an application in Android Studio.
I have a problem when I try to change the text of a TextView that belongs to a Dialog.
I think the problem is because I'm trying to do a setText inside to an interface.
This is my Dialog.

```
 private void showDialogDeEspera() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_de_carga_o_espera, null, false);
    builder.setView(view);
    dialogEspera = builder.create();
    textEspera = view.findViewById(R.id.text_dialog_carga_o_espera);
    progresoPing = view.findViewById(R.id.progress_carga_o_espera);
    progresoPing.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    dialogEspera.show();
}
```

and this is my interface where I get the response and where I try to modify the text.

```
ResponsePingWs rpw = new ResponsePingWs() {
        @Override
        public void responsePing(String error) {
            validarRespuesta(error);
        }
};
```

the validarRespuesta Method is where you try to modify the text with the error.

```
private void validarRespuesta(String error){
    if (error.equals("")){
        textEspera.setText("No se puede accesar al servisor");
        SystemClock.sleep(3000);
        Toast.makeText(this, "No se pudo acceder al servidor, revisar URL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        dialogEspera.dismiss();
    }else if (error.equals("success")){
        textEspera.setText("Coneción exitosa!");
        SystemClock.sleep(3000);
        Toast.makeText(this, "El servidor respondió correctamente!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        dialogEspera.dismiss();
    }else if (!error.equals("") && !errorPing.equals("success")){
        textEspera.setText(error);
        SystemClock.sleep(3000);
        Toast.makeText(this, "El servidor respondió con un mensaje de error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        dialogEspera.dismiss();
    }
}
```

If anyone has an idea or solution in this regard, I would greatly appreciate it if you could help me, thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to call interfacePing method from background thread? In android, Views can only modify in main thread. May be you can try by putting runOnUiThread.

Comment: In fact, I call the method of my interface from the Volley Response Listener

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Dhaval Shah
I used the runOnUiThread and if it worked!.

```
 final ResponsePingWs rpw = new ResponsePingWs() {
                    @Override
                    public void responsePing(String error, Context context) {
                        runThread(error, context);
                    }
                };
                pingAPI(getApplicationContext(), rpw);
```

and this is the runThread method that I will implement

```
private void runThread(final String error, final Context context) {

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
                try {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (error.equals("")){
                                textEspera.setText("No se puede accesar al servisor");
                                SystemClock.sleep(3000);
                                Toast.makeText(context, "No se pudo acceder al servidor, revisar URL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                dialogEspera.dismiss();
                            }else if (error.equals("success")){
                                textEspera.setText("Coneción exitosa!");
                                SystemClock.sleep(3000);
                                Toast.makeText(context, "El servidor respondió correctamente!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                dialogEspera.dismiss();
                            }else if (!error.equals("") && !errorPing.equals("success")){
                                textEspera.setText(error);
                                SystemClock.sleep(3000);
                                Toast.makeText(context, "El servidor respondió con un mensaje de error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                dialogEspera.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }.start();
}
```